# Is there a better way to write the same code as mine?

Tags: java, if-statement

i want to write this code as a vowel finder that exclude number and sign or symbol is there a better way beside add them one by one ? the code is working fine but i think there is a better way to do this . I'm new to java i just learn in 2 week ago.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ConsonantOrVowel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char c;
        System.out.println("Please Input a Character: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        c=input.next().charAt(0);
        if(c == '1'|| c == '2'|| c == '3'|| c == '4'|| c == '5' ||c == '6' ||c == '7'||c == '8'||c == '9'|| c == '!'|| c == '@' ||c == '#' ||c == '$'||c == '%'||c == '^'|| c == '&'|| c == '*' ||c == '(' ||c == ')'||c == '_'||c == '+'|| c == '-'|| c == '/'||c == '['|| c == ']'|| c == '{' ||c == '}' ||c == ';'||c == ':'||c == '"'|| c == ','|| c == '.'|| c == '?'){
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
        else if(c == 'A'|| c == 'a'|| c == 'E' ||c == 'e' ||c == 'I'||c == 'i'||c == 'O'||c == 'o'||c == 'U'||c == 'u') {
            System.out.println("Input Character is a Vowel");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Input Character is a Consonant");
    }
}
```

Comment: My first thought would be to use one or more arrays or `java.util.List` to store the values you are looking for (and/or want to exclude).  Since `java.util.List` has `contains`, you could simply do a single line check to see if your input is within the include or exclude list

Comment: You can create a `Pattern` of vowels and consonants then match your input to the patterns.

Comment: Do you know about typecasting? For simple input like this you could convert your char `c` into its respective int value and check if your int value was within a certain range with [an ascii table](https://ascii.cl/). For example, if you convert the char `H` to an int, you would get `72`. This only works effectively with a range of ascii though. For vowels, you can check something like `"aeiou".contains(letter)` where letter is a `String` variable of length 1.

Comment: Entry Not Valid: `if(!Character.toString(c).matches("(?i)[a-z]")) {`. Entry is a Vowel: `else if(Character.toString(c).matches("(?i)[aeiou]")) {`. Otherwise it's a Consonant.

Comment: This question may be a better fit for [codereview.se] (though read their rules first).

Answer (score 2):

You could use `String.inxedOf(char c)`:

```
public class ConsonantOrVowel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char c;
        System.out.println("Please Input a Character: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        c = input.next().charAt(0);

        if ("123456789!@#$%^&*()_+-/[]{};:\",.?".indexOf(c) > -1) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        } else if ("AaEeIiOoUu".indexOf(c) > -1) {
            System.out.println("Input Character is a Vowel");
        } else
            System.out.println("Input Character is a Consonant");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Plain old arrays

You could start by using some arrays...

```
char[] exclude = new char[]{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '+', '-', '/', '[', ']', '{', '}', ';', ':', '"', ',', '.', '?'};
char[] include = new char[]{'A', 'a', 'E', 'e', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u'};

System.out.println("Please Input a Character: ");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
char c = input.next().charAt(0);
boolean shouldExclude = false;
for (char value : exclude) {
    if (value == c) {
        shouldExclude = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (shouldExclude) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
} else {
    boolean isIncluded = false;
    for (char value : include) {
        if (value == c) {
            shouldExclude = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isIncluded) {
        System.out.println("Input Character is a Vowel");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Input Character is a Consonant");
    }
}
```

This is a little bit long winded, but is easily updated

## `java.util.List`

You make use of the `List` class from the collections API, which has a `contains` method, which makes checking the `List` for matching elements much easier...

```
Character[] exclude = new Character[]{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '_', '+', '-', '/', '[', ']', '{', '}', ';', ':', '"', ',', '.', '?'};
Character[] include = new Character[]{'A', 'a', 'E', 'e', 'I', 'i', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'u'};

List<Character> excludeList = Arrays.asList(exclude);
List<Character> includeList = Arrays.asList(include);

System.out.println("Please Input a Character: ");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
char c = input.next().charAt(0);
if (excludeList.contains(c)) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
} else if (includeList.contains(c)) {
    System.out.println("Input Character is a Vowel");
} else {
    System.out.println("Input Character is a Consonant");
}
```

## Use `String`

Okay, this is similar to using `List`, but because we're only interested in a single character match is slightly easier to setup

```
String exclude = "123456789!@#$%^&*()_+-/[]{};:\",.?";
String include = "AaEeIiOoUu";

System.out.println("Please Input a Character: ");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
char c = input.next().charAt(0);
String value = Character.toString(c);
if (exclude.contains(value)) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
} else if (include.contains(value)) {
    System.out.println("Input Character is a Vowel");
} else {
    System.out.println("Input Character is a Consonant");
}
```

## Regular expression

This one's a little more complicated, but is extremely powerful (and regular expressions are something your should take the time to learn)

```
String excludePattern = "[0-9\\!@#\\$\\^&\\*\\(\\)_+-/\\[\\]{};:\",\\.\\?%]";
String includePattern = "[AaEeIiOoUu]";

System.out.println("Please Input a Character: ");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
char c = input.next().charAt(0);
String value = Character.toString(c);
if (value.matches(excludePattern)) {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
} else if (value.matches(includePattern)) {
    System.out.println("Input Character is a Vowel");
} else {
    System.out.println("Input Character is a Consonant");
}
```

## And probably some other way I've not thought at...

As I've demonstrated, there is more than one way to approach/solve this problem.  Which one(s) you use will depend a lot on what you are trying to achieve, the input you have available and the desired output

Comment: So, even after presenting at least 4 different ways to solve the problem, this still attracts a downvote ... be interested in knowing why - and yes, there are probably a lot of other ways to achieve it, I did say that ;)

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the real problem with your code is that this is not correct.

```
    else
        System.out.println("Input Character is a Consonant");
```

That is making a fundamentally incorrect assumption.   You are assuming that all characters that are not in the previous two sets *must be* consonants.

- What about SP (space), HT (tab) and various other control characters?
- What about LATIN-1 accented characters, currency symbols and so on?
- What about Cyrillic, Indian, Thai, and other scripts?
- What about Chinese, Japanese, Korean and other ideographic character sets?

OK, so what is the solution?  How do you deal with this?

The correct way is to use the methods provided by the `Character` class.   Something like this:

```
if (Character.isLetter(...)) {
    if (/* character is upper or lower case a,e,i,o,u */) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
} else {
    ... 
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to restrict your classification to the English alphabet (i.e. A through Z, a through z, no accents, etcetera) then a simple way is to do this:

```
if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'A' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'E' ||) {
    ch == 'i' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'O' ||
    ch == 'u' || ch == 'U') {
    ...
} else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' || ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```